# New Custom Field to be used as Automation Condition

Tags: acumatica

I need to differentiate the recipient of Notification for every changes made on Task screen based on new custom field (Type).

[image]

My problem is that this new custom field can't be found when configuring condition on Automation Notification

[image]

Please help, how to enable this new field to be available for use as condition parameter on Automation Notification configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to have more detail on your code for the extended field and the subject you are using for the Automation.

I have tested this successfully with extension libraries, so you may need to convert your extension project into an extension library.

[image]

This means you would need to compile the extension code into a DLL but it should work with what you need.

You can find more info in the Acumatica reference site:
 http://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=a3278167-2285-4c92-8404-367952b42d9e.

Comment: Hi @Arsiadi, was this answer helpful? If so, could you please accept it?

Comment: Hello @Markoan, I just create new field without any particular code that need to be written thanks to Acumatica framework. So, I don't think putting the code is necessary here. Anyway, converting the customization to dll can resolve my problem. Thanks for your advice.